SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
I created my database in SQL Server with the code first method in ASP.NET Core. My intention is to build a simple news site. I have two tables in one of which I create news groups and it is successful in the other. I have to select that news group from my tables and add descriptions, photos, etc.
When I click on record, I get this error:

SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Pages_PageGroups_PageGroupGroupID". The conflict occurred in database "dbNews", table "dbo.PageGroups", column "GroupID".

I suppose it is for the subject of dependency injection, but I did not try it.
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace toplern18.Models
{
    public class Page
    {
        [Key]
        public int PagrID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "عنوان گروه")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا{0} را وارد نمایید")]
        public int GroupID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "عنوان")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا{0} را وارد نمایید")]
        [MaxLength(250)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "توضیح مختصر")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا{0} را وارد نمایید")]
        [MaxLength(350)]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "متن")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا{0} را وارد نمایید")]
        [MaxLength(400)]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string text { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "بازدید")]
        public int visit { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "تصویر")]
        public string ImageName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "اسلاید")]
        public bool ShowDlider { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "تاریخ ایجاد")]
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        //الان این اون یکه است
        public virtual PageGroup PageGroup { get; set; }

        public virtual List<PageComment> PageComment { get; set; }

        public Page()
        {
        }
    }
}

-------------

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace toplern18.Models
{
    public class PageGroup
    {
        [Key]
        public int GroupID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "عنوان گروه")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا{0} را وارد نمایید")]
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string GroupTitle { get; set; }


        //رابطش با پیج یک به چند است  الان لیست اون چنده است
         public virtual List<Page> Page { get; set; } //برقراری رابطه

        public PageGroup()
        {
            //سازنده خالی
        }
    }
}


Post the code where you actually insert your record.

It is still unclear from the code you have provided but my hunch is that you are inserting and not updating. The error tells that it's a ForeignKey, which seems like the row should be unique to me. You'll need to provide more details about the table relationships for us to be more helpful on this one.

Unlikely to be DI more likely your database design isn't as you require. But more details required.

When you configure the entity relationship without configuring the foreign key in DbContext, Entity Framework Core will automatically generate the foreign key according to the convention. For example, the PageGroupGroupID in the Page table.


This will cause database errors when you insert data.
Solution:
You can configure the correct foreign key relationship in the DbContext:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Page>()
     .HasOne(p => p.PageGroup)
     .WithMany(pg => pg.Page)
     .HasForeignKey(p => p.GroupID)
     .IsRequired();

     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}


